# Publishing IOS7 app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios7, ios8, xcode5.1

I just finished my IOS7 app using Xcode 5.1.1 and targeted for IOS 7.0 and later, the question is: Since  Apple just released IOS8 can I still publish my app or I need to update it?

Comment: try to publish it and you will get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes u can publish the application for now there is no restriction but you need to submit screen shot for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus of your current application.

Comment: ok thanks a lot! But what kind of screenshot should I send? For example some Views of the App? And also, how can I create the screenshots? Because i'm still using xcode 5.1.1 not xcode 6 so I have no Iphone 6 simulator (if it exists)

Comment: No other way to take screen shot from xcode 6 .You can take help from designer for this

Comment: iPhone 6 have 1334x750 pixel and iPhone 6 have 1920x1080 pixel resolution. Design your screen shots for these resolutions.